# How to save changed state of dynamic created UISwitch in CoreData model in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, uiswitch

I have a `UITableView` containing dynamic cells added by user. Each cell has one `UILabel` and one `UISwitch`. The default state of switch is ON. I save these values in a `CoreData` model (`UILabel` as String & `UISwitch` as `Bool`) whenever user adds it. 
I would like to update/store the state of switch corresponding to value of label in the same cell in CoreData model whenever user toggles the switch. I have added tags (switch.tag = indexPath.row) to each switch in row and can access it by using sender.tag in my cellChanged function. But I am not able to fetch label of that row in which switch has been toggled. If I can somehow fetch value of label corresponding to the switch toggled then I can run a for loop to look for that label value in `CoreData` model and then subsequently set state of `UISwitch`. Since I am using `Swift` language, I will appreciate if you can explain code using the same.

Comment: Why do you need to store the label in CoreData, do these labels change?

Comment: These labels store the value of time picked by user.

Comment: Fair enough. May I assume that you store the `NSDate`s?

Comment: Yes NSDates as String

Comment: You should not try to get the value of the label in order to determine which CoreData object has been updated.  You should get the object directly from your datasource using the sender.tag (ie indexPath.row).

Comment: Although I know it can be done using tag and indexPath but could not do it. Can you show an example code in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
func switchTapped(sender:UISwitch) {
let switchPosition = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(switchPosition)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better pattern can be creating a protocol in cell. something like

```
@protocol MyCellDelegate{
func cellSwitchChanged(forCell: MyCell, toValue: Bool, withLabel: String?)
}

class MyCell: UITableVeiwCell{
weak veer delegate: MyCellDelegate
.
.
.

@IBaction handleSwitchChanged(sender: UISwitch){
self.delegate?.cellSwitchChanged(forCell: self, toValue: sender.value, withLabel: self.lblName.text) 
}
}
```

And in you cell for row an indexPath, assign you vc to be delegate of the cell. and override this method.

So every time the switch changes, the view controller will get the cell reference, switch value and the text label. you can then do your core data update operation here.